# How do I install OpenGLUT?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm trying to install OpenGLUT in ubuntu and I've downloaded it from sourceforge, but I cannot copy it to the /usr directory because it says I don't have the proper permissions. I've tried using the sudo cp terminal command but it won't work since I'll have to copy individual files, and let's face it, there should be a more efficient method of copying stuff. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could run 'sudo -i' to get a root-shell and then do all your copying from there.
If you want to use nautilus you could try:

```
gksu "nautilus --no-desktop"
```

from a terminal or the run dialog. That will start nautilus as the root user.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could copy multiple files with `cp` by using the `-R` parameter. For example,

```
sudo cp -R /path/to/your/folder /usr
```